# replyAllHeaderWithExcludedRecipients seems not working

Tags: ios, swift, mailcore2

I would like to reply all except the sender. If I use replyAllHeaderWithExcludedRecipients(nil), it always cc's the sender address. So I added an array of MCOAddress objects. It still does the same thing. How can I fix this?

```
var builder = MCOMessageBuilder()

builder.header = originalHeader.replyAllHeaderWithExcludedRecipients([MCOAddress(mailbox: USER_EMAIL)])
builder.header.from = MCOAddress(displayName: USER_FULL_NAME, mailbox: USER_EMAIL)
builder.htmlBody = body
```

Values of the constants:

```
let USER_EMAIL = "versiful@gmail.com"
let USER_FULL_NAME = "Versiful Team"
```

the content of originalHeader:

```
<mailcore::MessageHeader:0x7fc70a6142a0
Message-ID: 2e7a244c-26ba-4453-b56d-61c5af6c0d28@le-huangs-macbook.local
References: [CAHv7PYbHA2qFMXwNqNjcfeb9Tc122CBOtAa4QiVk2axaXou06g@mail.gmail.com,CAGyw0=CySHNZb7ECsRVxL6M7CHvH3S3TN2rmwYe=VbyRszUrUg@mail.gmail.com,f5bbf053-90ad-4ff6-a477-ae4b0ca43b9e@D-10-65-18-183.dhcp4.washington.edu]
In-Reply-To: [f5bbf053-90ad-4ff6-a477-ae4b0ca43b9e@D-10-65-18-183.dhcp4.washington.edu]
Sender: mailcore::Address:0x7fc70a61cf50 Versiful Team <versiful@gmail.com>
From: mailcore::Address:0x7fc70a61d440 Versiful Team <versiful@gmail.com>
To: [mailcore::Address:0x7fc70a61deb0 Versiful Team <versiful@gmail.com>]
Cc: [mailcore::Address:0x7fc70a61e420 Le Grace Huang <rock3m@gmail.com>]
Reply-To: [mailcore::Address:0x7fc70a61d930 Versiful Team <versiful@gmail.com>]
Subject: Re: Re: Fwd: Wav5
>
```

Result from connection logger:

```
Connectionlogger: Date: Wed, 9 Sep 2015 09:57:01 -0700
From: Versiful Team <versiful@gmail.com>
To: Versiful Team <versiful@gmail.com>
Cc: Le Grace Huang <rock3m@gmail.com>
Message-ID: <ba8120c1-86c4-46f8-8c3e-2fd533f232bc@D-10-65-18-183.dhcp4.washington.edu>
In-Reply-To: <5de96028-6afe-4221-83e5-46aad848add3@D-10-65-18-183.dhcp4.washington.edu>
References: <CAHv7PYbHA2qFMXwNqNjcfeb9Tc122CBOtAa4QiVk2axaXou06g@mail.gmail.com>
 <CAGyw0=CySHNZb7ECsRVxL6M7CHvH3S3TN2rmwYe=VbyRszUrUg@mail.gmail.com>
 <f5bbf053-90ad-4ff6-a477-ae4b0ca43b9e@D-10-65-18-183.dhcp4.washington.edu>
 <2e7a244c-26ba-4453-b56d-61c5af6c0d28@le-huangs-macbook.local>
 <8e06306c-66b2-46e9-8a57-e3244e78fdc4@le-huangs-macbook.local>
 <785ed09d-e97f-4f51-9ab3-4097c6197918@le-huangs-macbook.local>
 <5be8c690-57ed-44ce-b860-7fc3d858676f@D-10-65-18-183.dhcp4.washington.edu>
 <277bf264-55e0-4240-9f3e-d008c6100c80@D-10-65-18-183.dhcp4.washington.edu>
 <5de96028-6afe-4221-83e5-46aad848add3@D-10-65-18-183.dhcp4.washington.edu>
Subject: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Fwd: Wav5
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="55f064dd_327b23c6_2d51"
```

Comment: Could you show me what the content of originalHeader and a specific example of USER_FULL_NAME and USER_EMAIL?

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà thanks for taking a look! I just updated the info you needed.

Comment: Could you show me the result you got? Thanks.

Comment: Updated with the result from connection logger

Comment: I think that it's the behavior whenever the From or Sender field matches one of the emails you gave as parameter.